# Using the Barracuda REST API with Ansible - token authentication doesn't work

Tags: rest, api, curl, ansible

I'm trying to use the [REST API by Barracuda ADC and/or WAF](https://campus.barracuda.com/resources/attachments/application/42049757/BarracudaLoadBalancerADC_REST-API-Guide.pdf) and, while it works when I use cURL (from the documentation):

Request:

```
$ curl
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}' \ http://10.11.19.104:8000/restapi/v2/login
```

Response:

> {"token":"eyJldCI6IjEzODAyMzE3NTciLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImY3NzY2ZTFmNTgwMzgyNmE1YTAzZWZlMzcy\nYzgzOTMyIiwidXNlciI6ImFkbWluIn0=\n"}

Then we should use that token to execute commands on the API, something like:

```
$ curl
-X GET \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \ 
-u 'eyJldCI6IjEzODAyMzE3NTciLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImY3NzY2ZTFmNTgwMzgyNmE1YTAzZWZlMzcy\nYzgzOTMyIiwidXNlciI6ImFkbWluIn0=\n': \
http://10.11.19.104:8000/restapi/v2/virtual_service_groups
```

And it'll give me a response listing (in this case) my virtual service groups, and it works with cURL.

Now, when I try to use ansible to do the same things, the first step to authenticate goes successfully (I can even use the generated token with cURL and it accepts it), but the second step to run the commands with the generated token always gives me 401 error (Invalid credentials):

```
- name: login into the load balancer
  uri:
    url: "{{ barracuda_url }}/login"
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body:
      username: "{{ barracuda_user }}"
      password: "{{ barracuda_pass }}"
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    return_content: yes
    force_basic_auth: yes
  register: login
  tags: login, debug

- debug: msg="{{ login.json.token }}"
  tags: debug

- name: get
  uri:
    url: "{{ barracuda_url }}/virtual_service_groups"
    method: GET
    body_format: json
    user: "{{ login.json.token }}:"
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    return_content: yes
    force_basic_auth: yes
  register: response
```

Output of my playbook:

```
TASK [loadbalancer : login into the load balancer] *****************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [loadbalancer : debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "eyJldCI9IjE0ODQ2MDcxNTAiXCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IjRmM2TlYWMwN2ExNmUxYWFhNGEwNTU5NTMw\nZGQ3ZmM3IiwiaXNlciI6IndpYSJ9\n"
}

TASK [loadbalancer : get] ******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"error\":{\"msg\":\"Please log in to get valid token\",\"status\":401,\"type\":\"Invalid Credentials\"}}", "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf8", "date": "Mon, 16 Jan 2017 22:32:30 GMT", "failed": true, "json": {"error": {"msg": "Please log in to get valid token", "status": 401, "type": "Invalid Credentials"}}, "msg": "Status code was not [200]: HTTP Error 401: ", "redirected": false, "server": "BarracudaHTTP 4.0", "status": 401, "transfer_encoding": "chunked", "url": "http://10.11.19.104:8000/restapi/v2/virtual_service_groups"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colon from `"{{ login.json.token }}:"` in `user` argument. Use:

```
user: "{{ login.json.token }}"
```

The colon is not a part of a username, but a `curl` syntax (used in your example to avoid an interactive password prompt):

> ```
> -u, --user <user:password>
>     [ ]
>     If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.
> ```

Comment: Almost! With a bit of test and error (plus wireshark) I found that I need to remove the colon AND add an empty password parameter:

```user: "{{ login.json.token }}"
    password: ""```

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/urls.py#L980) ensures that regardless if you specify an empty password or do not specify it at all, the resulting value passed to the server will be the same. I don't quite understand why you'd need to add it.

Comment: Without that line, it didn't pass anything at all (I checked on wireshark, there was only the username/token value, without empty field for password).